# Area of the equilateral triangle formed by (x,y) satisfying given curve

Tags: geometry, polynomials, analytic-geometry

I am asked to find Area of the equilateral triangle formed by $(x,y)$ satisfying given curve $x^3+y^3+3xy=1$

I can find no way to find the points on this curve that satisfy an equilateral triangle. Looking at the polynomial I get $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(-1,-1)$ as its solutions, don't know how that could possibly help.

I can't even find a way to reduce this polynomial using the traditional formulae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz = \dfrac{1}{2}(x+y+z)[(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2]$$

So, for our problem
\begin{equation}
   x^3+y^3 + 3xy = 1\\
   \Rightarrow\quad \dfrac{1}{2}(x+y-1)[(x-y)^2+(y+1)^2+(x+1)^2]  = 0\\
\end{equation}
Since $\dfrac{1}{2}[(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2] > 0$, if $x = y \neq -1$, this is an equation for the straight line $x+y+1=0$ and a single point $(-1,-1)$.

We can find the area from here.